# Change listview items in tab based on tab positon

Tags: android

All tabs are showing same list contents. Need help in Menufragment.class to access the corresponding category items according to tab position

Expected Result : I need to display 4 mutton items in first tab, 8 sea food in second tab,5 Noodles in third tab, 7 egg items in fourth tab and 13 Veg dishes in fifth tab.

Actual Result : All tabs are displaying the list of 13 Vegetarian Dishes items.

Main Activity

```
JSONObject hotels = obj.getJSONObject("Menu");
JSONArray items = hotels.getJSONArray("Items");
                for (int j = 0; j < items.length(); j++) {

                    JSONObject hotel = items.getJSONObject(j);
                    categoryname = hotel.getString("name");
                    System.out.println(categoryname);

                    JSONArray hotelmenu = hotel.getJSONArray(categoryname);
                    //categoryitems = new ArrayList<List<Menuclass>>(hotelmenu.length());
                    listitems = new ArrayList<Menuclass>(hotelmenu.length());
                    List<Menuclass> list = new ArrayList<Menuclass>(hotelmenu.length());
                   // categoryitems.add(list);
                    for (int i = 0; i < hotelmenu.length(); i++) {
                        System.out.println(hotelmenu.length());
                        JSONObject menuitems = hotelmenu.getJSONObject(i);
                        itemname = menuitems.getString("name");
                        itemsprice = menuitems.getString("price");
                        itemtype = menuitems.getString("veg");
                        int itemtypeint = Integer.parseInt(itemtype);
                    //    System.out.println(menuitems[i]);
                        if (itemtypeint == 0) {

                            list.add(new Menuclass(itemname, itemsprice, R.drawable.nonveg));
                            //  categoryitems.add(Arrays.asList(new Menuclass(itemname,itemtype,R.drawable.nonveg)));
                        }
                        else {

                            list.add(new Menuclass(itemname, itemsprice, R.drawable.vegicon));
                          //  categoryitems.add(Arrays.asList(new Menuclass(itemname, itemtype, R.drawable.vegicon)));
                        }
                        listitems=list;
                    }

                   // System.out.println(categoryitems);
                    System.out.println(listitems);
                    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText((categoryname)));

                    ViewPagerAdapter1 adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter1(getSupportFragmentManager(), items);
                    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }
```

Menufragment.class

```
public class Menufragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

Context context;

public Menufragment() {
// Required empty public constructor
}

public static Fragment getInstance(int position) {
Menufragment fragment = new Menufragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("position", position);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

// Inflate the layout for this fragment
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_menu1, container, false);
int position = getArguments().getInt("position", 0);

// set your list base on position
    // list 01x
ListView listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.Listview1);
System.out.println(MenumainActivity.listitems);
***MenuViewAdapter listViewAdapter = new MenuViewAdapter(getActivity(), MenumainActivity.listitems);***
    listview.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
return view;
}
}

class ViewPagerAdapter1 extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private JSONArray jsonArray;

public ViewPagerAdapter1(FragmentManager manager, JSONArray jsonArray) {
super(manager);
this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
return Menufragment.getInstance(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
return jsonArray.length();
}
}
```

JSON Response

{"Menu":{"Items":[{"id":1,"code":"hot1_sub1_mnu","name":"Mutton","status":"1","Mutton":[{"id":1,"code":"hot1_sub1_mut","name":"Mutton Peper Fry","price":"100","veg":"0"},{"id":2,"code":"hot1_sub2_mut","name":"Mutton Curry","price":"100","veg":"0"},{"id":3,"code":"hot1_sub3_mut","name":"Mutton Rogan Josh","price":"100","veg":"0"},{"id":4,"code":"hot1_sub4_mut","name":"Mutton Mohalai","price":"100","veg":"0"}]},{"id":2,"code":"hot1_sub2_mnu","name":"Sea Food","status":"1","Sea Food":[{"id":1,"code":"hot1_sub1_sf","name":"Fish Fry","price":"150","veg":"0"},{"id":2,"code":"hot1_sub2_sf","name":"Chilly Fish","price":"250","veg":"0"},{"id":3,"code":"hot1_sub3_sf","name":"Finger Fish","price":"350","veg":"0"},{"id":4,"code":"hot1_sub4_sf","name":"Prawn Pepper Fry","price":"180","veg":"0"},{"id":5,"code":"hot1_sub5_sf","name":"Chilly Prawn","price":"150","veg":"0"},{"id":6,"code":"hot1_sub6_sf","name":"Golden Fried Prawn","price":"210","veg":"0"},{"id":7,"code":"hot1_sub7_sf","name":"Fish Malabar Curry","price":"300","veg":"0"},{"id":8,"code":"hot1_sub8_sf","name":"Prawn Curry","price":"130","veg":"0"}]},{"id":3,"code":"hot1_sub3_mnu","name":"Noodels","status":"1","Noodels":[{"id":1,"code":"hot1_sub1_nd","name":"Chicken Noodels","price":"70","veg":"0"},{"id":2,"code":"hot1_sub2_nd","name":"Egg Noodles","price":"60","veg":"0"},{"id":3,"code":"hot1_sub3_nd","name":"Veg Noodles","price":"55","veg":"1"},{"id":4,"code":"hot1_sub4_nd","name":"Mix Noodles","price":"80","veg":"1"},{"id":5,"code":"hot1_sub1_nd","name":"Scezwan Chicken Noodles","price":"60","veg":"0"}]},{"id":4,"code":"hot1_sub4_mnu","name":"Egg","status":"1","Egg":[{"id":1,"code":"hot1_sub1_egg","name":"Scrambled Egg","price":"20","veg":"0"},{"id":2,"code":"hot1_sub2_egg","name":"Omelet","price":"20","veg":"0"},{"id":3,"code":"hot3_sub3_egg","name":"Masala Omlete","price":"25","veg":"0"},{"id":4,"code":"hot3_sub4_egg","name":"Fried Egg (2 nos)","price":"20","veg":"0"},{"id":5,"code":"hot1_sub5_egg","name":"Boiled Egg(2 nos)","price":"20","veg":"0"},{"id":6,"code":"hot1_sub6_egg","name":"Egg Podimas","price":"25","veg":"0"},{"id":7,"code":"hot1_sub7_egg","name":"Egg Curry/ Masala","price":"50","veg":"0"}]},{"id":5,"code":"hot1_sub5_mnu","name":"Vegetarian Dishes","status":"1","Vegetarian Dishes":[{"id":1,"code":"hot1_sub1_veg","name":"Veg./ Gobi Man.Dry","price":"60","veg":"1"},{"id":2,"code":"hot1_sub2_veg","name":"Panner Manchoorian Dry","price":"60","veg":"1"},{"id":3,"code":"hot1_sub3_veg","name":"Dhal Fry","price":"50","veg":"1"},{"id":4,"code":"hot1_sub4_veg","name":"Mix Veg Curry","price":"50","veg":"1"},{"id":5,"code":"hot1_sub5_veg","name":"Aloo Gobi Masala","price":"50","veg":"1"},{"id":6,"code":"hot1_sub6_veg","name":"Green Peas masala","price":"50","veg":"1"},{"id":7,"code":"hot1_sub7_veg","name":"Chenna Masala","price":"50","veg":"1"},{"id":8,"code":"hot1_sub8_veg","name":"Kadai vegetable","price":"60","veg":"1"},{"id":9,"code":"hot1_sub9_veg","name":"Veg Kolapuri","price":"60","veg":"1"},{"id":10,"code":"hot1_sub10_veg","name":"Malai Kuftha Curry","price":"60","veg":"1"},{"id":11,"code":"hot1_sub11_veg","name":"Panner Butter Masala","price":"60","veg":"1"},{"id":12,"code":"hot1_sub11_veg","name":"Mushroom Dry / Gravy","price":"70","veg":"1"},{"id":13,"code":"hot1_sub12_veg","name":"Boiled Vegetables","price":"50","veg":"1"}]}]},"status":"true"}

Comment: do you have three fragments for three different tabs?

Comment: No. Single fragment because tabs should be created dynamically based on number of categories

Comment: got it, would you share your json response?

Comment: hummm...mutton...

Comment: seems issue in `getInstance(int position)`, how are you using it?

Answer (score 0):

initialize your list inside for loop :

```
 listitems = new ArrayList<Menuclass>(hotelmenu.length());
                    List<Menuclass> list = new ArrayList<Menuclass>(hotelmenu.length());
```

this line put inside for loop

Comment: Did it. But only the last item of last category is displayed in all tabs.

Comment: only put this line inside  List<Menuclass> list = new ArrayList<Menuclass>(hotelmenu.length());

Comment: Did it. Still same. Last item of last category is displayed in all tab

Comment: can you please give me your response?

Answer (score 0):

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONObject jsonObject_Menu = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Menu");
            JSONArray jsonArray_Items = jsonObject_Menu.getJSONArray("Items");

            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray_Items.length(); i++){
                JSONArray jsonArray_Mutton = jsonArray_Items.optJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("Mutton");
                for(int j=0; j<jsonArray_Mutton.length(); j++){
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray_Mutton.optJSONObject(j);
                    map.put("name", "name");
                    map.put("price", "price");
                    map.put("veg", "veg");
                    arrayList.add(map);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Use Parsing like this and then pass arraylist set value in listview

```
tvName.setText(arrayList.get(position).get("name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this solution and lemme know if it works.
pass your list here

`ViewPagerAdapter1 adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter1(getSupportFragmentManager(), items);`

and change your `ViewPagerAdapter1` accordingly.

After that in `public static Fragment getInstance(int position)` pass the same list as well, you can serialize it to include into bundle. And in your fragment rather doing this `MenumainActivity.listitems` to get list, get the list from bundle and pass it to your adapter.

hope it will resolve your issue.